# Solving for x in a equation involving natural logarithms

Tags: logarithms

How would I solve for x in this equation here:

$$\ln(x)+\ln(1/x+1)=3$$

I realize that the answer is $e^3-1$, but I am not sure as to how to get it.
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Use the fact that $\log (xy) = \log x + \log y$. Then exponentiate.

Comment: Thanks, how silly of me to forget that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \ln x + \ln \left( \frac{1}{x} + 1 \right) = \ln \left( x(1/x + 1) \right) = 3 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ln(x+1)= 3 \Rightarrow x + 1 = e^3 \Rightarrow x = e^3 - 1 $$

Answer (score 2):

We know that $ln(a)+ ln(b) =ln(ab)$

Then,

$$ln(x)+ln(\frac{1}{x})=ln(x(\frac{1}{x}+1)=ln(1+x)=3$$

Now,

We know that $e^{ln(a)}=a$

Then, $$e^{ln(1+x)}=e^3 $$

This implies that $$x+1=e^3 \implies x=e^3-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\ln(x)+\ln\left(\frac 1{x+1}\right)=\ln\left(\frac x{x+1}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $\ln{x}+\ln{y}=\ln{xy}$ to simplify; the equation becomes much simpler.